# Dynamic URL queries with AngularJS and NodeJS, MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, query-string

I really do not understand how to handle URLs with queries appended to it.

I have endpoints that accept several parameters like:

```
?max_length=50,
?min_length=1,
?active=true,
?only_today=true,
?etc...
```

Via AngularJS how can I set those value dynamically only if the user has checked for those values?

Actually I'm just building an object `{}` appending those parameters when the $scope is not null. But I don't think it is a good idea.

Same for NodeJS and MongoDB...
How can I get the correct object based on the query string on the URL?

What I'm doing here as well is to split up the URL and checking for the words, etc... I'm sure there is a better way and I can not find it in both documentations and wondering to bigger and bigger URL parameters it start to be hell.

I know this is a real low level question but I don't really understand how to handle it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $location service for that.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$resource` to easily map your endPoints to your services. You should map your params to what is expected in your api. And if you have conditional parameters, you need to handle undefined params in your backend and ignore these params. For mapping your endpoints in nodeJS check out [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/)
For example:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).factory("myFactory", function($resource) {
  var YourResource = $resource('/rest/yourResource');
  var factory = {
    retriveMyResources: function(paramsQuery) {
      return YourResource.query(paramsQuery).$promise;
    }
  };
  return factory;
}).controller("myCtrl", function($scope, myFactory) {
  myFactory.retrieveMyResources({
    maxLength: $scope.maxLength,
    sortBy: $scope.sortBy
  }).then(function(result) {
    $scope.result = result
  })
})
```

Your node server

```
//App.js you initialize your server, and include your route files
(function() {
  var restify = require("restify");

  var server = restify.createServer({
    name: "test-server"
  });
  server.pre(restify.CORS());
  server.use(restify.gzipResponse());
  server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
  server.use(restify.queryParser());
  server.use(restify.bodyParser());
  server.use(restify.jsonp());

  require("./routes/your_resource_route.js")(server);

  server.listen("1921", function() {
    console.log('%s listening at %s environment: %s', server.name, server.url, process.env.NODE_ENV);
  });
})();
```

Example Route file

```
module.exports = function(server) {
  var yourResourceService = require("services/your_resource_service.js");

  server.get("rest/yourResource",
    function(req, res, next) {
      return yourResourceService.findResources(req.params.maxLength, req.params.sortBy).then(function(resources) {
        res.send(200, resources);
        next();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        res.send(500, err);
        next();
      }).done();
    }
  );
}
```

And your service file

```
module.exports = function(app_context) {
  var exampleService = {
    findItems: function(maxLength, sortBy) {
      var sortObject = {};
      sortObject[sortBy || DEFAULT_SORT] = -1;
      return Q(brandMongooseCollection.find({}).sort(sortObject).limit(maxLength || DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH).lean().exec());
    }
  };
  return exampleService;
};
```